# Can't open IntelliJ in terminal, Ubuntu Linux 16.04

Tags: ubuntu, intellij-idea, ubuntu-16.04

I've successfully installed IntelliJ IDEA (community edition) and Java (Version 10.0.2) on my Ubuntu Linux 16.04.  However, I want to be able to open files on the terminal (similar to being able to use 'code .' to open files in VS Code).

I did some research, and it says you need to open IntelliJ, go to "tools", and there will be an option that says "create command-line Launcher".  However, when I go there, that option isn't present.  The really strange thing is that if I go to settings -> menus and toolbars -> main menu -> tools, the "command-line launcher" function IS present, but nothing I do allows me to select it.

This isn't the end of the world if I can never get it to work, but it's a pain in the butt and slows down my work-speed.  Thanks for everyone's help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is [some logic](https://github.com/JetBrains/intellij-community/blob/beb601e190388510a9c69d119be8f64e361d0a08/platform/platform-impl/src/com/intellij/ide/actions/CreateLauncherScriptAction.java#L52) for this action to be available.

It will not be available in the following cases:

- The system is not Unix (not available on Windows, obviously)
- IDE was [installed via the Snaps package manager](https://blog.jetbrains.com/idea/2017/11/install-intellij-idea-with-snaps/) which creates launcher itself. Check the scripts you have in `/snap/bin`, like `/snap/bin/intellij-idea-ultimate`.
- You don't have `python` or `python3` binaries in `PATH`.

Comment: Wow, 176 lines of code just to open in the terminal?!

Anyway, I'm good on all 3 you mentioned, except I'm not sure how add this:  "You don't have python or python3 binaries in PATH."

Thanks for your help!

Comment: @GCarssow type `python` or `python3` in the terminal and see if it works.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply, yes I have Python (3.6.6) installed.

Comment: @GCarssow please [submit a ticket to support](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/requests/new) with [idea.log](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/articles/207241085).

Answer (score 0):

Have you ensured it's enabled in the menu options?

```
Settings > Appearance & Behavior > Menus and Toolbars
```

It might be placed in another menu, in which case you can move it.

If it's nowhere to be found, you should be able to add it at any spot you want.[image]

Comment: How do I enable/Disable parts on the Menus and Toolbars section?  I can't see anything related to that in Settings (and searching through IntelliJ showed nothing).

And yes, I've tried moving it around to make sure it is in the appropriate place, but it still won't appear in the Tools menu.

Comment: Sorry, "enable" was a bad choice of words...I just meant making sure it was visible and try moving it around. Just saw CrazyCoder's answer, which is probably on the right path.

Comment: Me too I have the same issue. I see it in the Appearance & Behavior | Main menu and toolbar, but it won't show up in The main menu. I tried to call it from the actions popup but the action also won't appear.